# Text Based Python Game

Tags: python, text-based

I can exit and get items but I cannot figure out where my issue with directions.   I am very new to python (first class) and this is our final project.  Any guidance on which line of code is incorrect would be greatly appreciated!

```
rooms={
'Locker Room': {'go South':'Storage Room', 'go West': 'Coaches Office', 'go North': 'Teachers Lounge', 'go East': 'Concession Stand', 'Item': 'gym clothes'},
'Storage Room':{'go North':'Locker Room','go East':'Cafeteria','Item': 'basketballs'},
'Cafeteria':{'go West':'Storage Room', 'Item': 'sports drinks'},
'Concession Stand':{'go West': 'Locker Room', 'go North': 'Gym', 'Item': 'nachos'},
'Coaches Office': {'go East': 'Locker Room', 'Item': 'team films'},
'Teachers Lounge': {'go South': 'Locker Room', 'go East': 'Math Class','Item': 'referees'},
'Math Class': {'go West': 'Teachers Lounge', 'Item': 'teammates'},
'Gym':{'Item' : 'basketball team'}
}
directions: set[str] = {'go North', 'go South', 'go East', 'go West'} #valid moves

def instructions():
    print('\n Welcome to the Battle of the Gym game')
    print('The basketball team has taken over the gym, and your volleyball match is set to begin in one hour.')
    print('You need to defeat the team before the opposing team arrives or forfeit your match.')
    print('But before you go to battle you will need a few items.')
    print('\n You must collect all 7 items to defeat the basketball team.')
    print('\n Move commands: go North, go South, go West, go East')
    print("\n Add to Inventory: get 'item name'")
    print('\n Exit game: exit')
    print('-------------------------------------------------------')
instructions() #prints the game title and how to play
#main loop
def main():
    location = 'Locker Room' #starting place
    inventory = [] #holds inventory

    def show_status(): #where I am, what i have or don't have, or what I need
        print('')
        print(f'You are currently in the {location}')
        print(f'You currently have: ', *inventory, sep=' ')
        if rooms[location]['Item'] in inventory:
           print('This room is empty.')
        else:
            print(f'You see ' + rooms[location]['Item'])

    while True:
        show_status() #prints current room and inventory
        possible_moves = rooms.get(location, {}) #looks for valid moves
        current_item = rooms[location]['Item'] #lets know item
        command = input('\nPlease enter a direction or take the available item: \n').strip().lower() #ask for users move
        if command in directions: #check for valid move
            if command not in rooms[location]: #if not valid command
                print("You can't go that way. Enter a new direction.")
            elif command in possible_moves: #valid move
                location = possible_moves.get(command, location)
                if location == 'Gym': #checks to see if game over
                    if len(inventory) != 7: #if inventory less than 7 game over
                       print("You've been beat! Game Over!")
                       break
                    else: #if inventory is 7 you won
                       print('Congratulations! You have collected all the items and defeated the basketball team!')
                       break
        elif command == 'exit': #exits game
            print("Thank you for playing. Hope you enjoyed the game.")
            break
        elif command == 'get {}'.format(current_item): #add item to inventory
            if current_item not in inventory: #checks inventory and if not in iventory retrieves item
                print('You got ' + current_item,'in your inventory.')
                inventory.append(current_item) #adds to inventory list
            elif current_item in inventory: #already in inventory list tells user that
                print('You already have this item.')
            else: #no items available to end loop
                print('No items available.')
        else: #user enters anything not in directions
            print('Invalid input.')
if __name__ =='__main__':
    main()
```

I tried changing rooms dictionary to go North and then directions to just north to match dictionary after the first set didn't work.

Comment: "*I cannot figure out where my issue with directions*" Please describe what is your expected behavior and what actual behavior are you getting instead. What input are you providing?

Comment: I'm guessing you use `.lower()` on the input, so `command` is all in lowercase, but your `directions` has uppercase characters. Example, if input is `go North`, then `command` is `go north`, but it will not match `go North`. You should just normalize `directions` to all be in lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

I've identified the issue in your code and provided a corrected version:

**The Problem:**

The issue lies in how you're checking for valid directions in the if command in rooms[location] line. This line only checks if the direction exists as a key in the current room's dictionary, not if the corresponding value points to another room.

**Code to the Solution:**

```py
rooms = {
    'Locker Room': {'go South': 'Storage Room', 'go West': 'Coaches Office', 'go North': 'Teachers Lounge', 'go East': 'Concession Stand', 'Item': 'gym clothes'},
    'Storage Room': {'go North': 'Locker Room', 'go East': 'Cafeteria', 'Item': 'basketballs'},
    'Cafeteria': {'go West': 'Storage Room', 'Item': 'sports drinks'},
    'Concession Stand': {'go West': 'Locker Room', 'go North': 'Gym', 'Item': 'nachos'},
    'Coaches Office': {'go East': 'Locker Room', 'Item': 'team films'},
    'Teachers Lounge': {'go South': 'Locker Room', 'go East': 'Math Class', 'Item': 'referees'},
    'Math Class': {'go West': 'Teachers Lounge', 'Item': 'teammates'},
    'Gym': {'Item': 'basketball team'}
}

directions: set[str] = {'go North', 'go South', 'go East', 'go West'}


def main():
    location = 'Locker Room'
    inventory = []

    def show_status():
        print('')
        print(f'You are currently in the {location}')
        print(f'You currently have: ', *inventory, sep=' ')
        if rooms[location]['Item'] in inventory:
            print('This room is empty.')
        else:
            print(f'You see ' + rooms[location]['Item'])

    while True:
        show_status()
        possible_moves = {key: value for key, value in rooms[location].items() if key in directions}  # Filter valid moves
        current_item = rooms[location]['Item']
        command = input('\nPlease enter a direction or take the available item: \n').strip().lower()

        if command in directions:
            if command not in possible_moves:  # Check if it's a valid move in the current room
                print("You can't go that way. Enter a new direction.")
            else:
                location = possible_moves[command]  # Update location based on valid move
                if location == 'Gym':
                    if len(inventory) != 7:
                        print("You've been beat! Game Over!")
                        break
                    else:
                        print('Congratulations! You have collected all the items and defeated the basketball team!')
                        break
        elif command == 'exit':
            print("Thank you for playing. Hope you enjoyed the game.")
            break
        elif command == 'get {}'.format(current_item):
            if current_item not in inventory:
                print('You got ' + current_item, 'in your inventory.')
                inventory.append(current_item)
            else:
                print('You already have this item.')
        else:
            print('Invalid input.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Explanation:**

**1. Filtering Valid Moves:** The `possible_moves` dictionary is created by iterating through the current room's items and filtering for keys that are also present in the `directions` set. This ensures you only consider valid directions from the current room.

**2. Checking Valid Moves:** The if command not in `possible_moves` check now verifies if the entered direction is actually a valid move from the current room, preventing invalid movements.

With this fix, your game should correctly handle user input for directions and allow players to navigate through the rooms as intended.

Comment: The `if command in directions` is still broken because the `input` return value is always lowered, but `directions` contains uppercase characters.

Comment: Thank you, I thought I was using the lower command to "fix" if they forgot to use uppercase but if I remove it I can move!  I will continue testing to verify but thank you!!